# Can I find a user's user_id with only their username for a Stack Exchange profile?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, api

Is there a way to get the user_id of either a global SE account (as is present in the network profile URL) or the account user_id associated with a local community with only a username?

It seems from [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98771/what-is-my-user-id) post that it is only possible to retrieve the user_id associated with a username by either knowing the user_id ahead of time (and then using it in the URL path) or by stumbling onto the user's profile and parsing the URL to retrieve the user_id.

I suppose I could retrieve the user_id for every user from the API and then search a specific username within that list to retrieve its associated user_id but that seems inefficient.

Is there a painless way of getting the user_id associated with a username? I'd like to do this programmatically.

Comment: Usernames are not unique and can change over time.

Comment: I see, thank you. So it seems if I was looking for something truly unique it would be the global SE account ID or a local community ID

Comment: If you're willing to wade through multiple results, you could probably pull this out of [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com) pretty easily.  But I'm not sure that actually solves your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the comments, usernames are not unique and can be changed for a given user ID.

Nevertheless, you can get a list of current name matches from the API using [the /users route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users).

For example:
    [/2.2/users?inname=mobet&site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users#order=desc&sort=reputation&inname=mobet&filter=!BTeB3PYn1aU(OSdNAwU_I9aq(i((tI&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

Currently yields (return fields filtered):

```
{
  "badge_counts": {"bronze": 15, "silver": 3, "gold": 0},
  "up_vote_count": 20,
  "answer_count": 3,
  "question_count": 15,
  "account_id": 3405853,
  "last_access_date": 1435873888,
  "reputation": 252,
  "user_id": 2856913,
  "display_name": "mobetta"
}, {
  "badge_counts": {"bronze": 11, "silver": 0, "gold": 0},
  "up_vote_count": 116,
  "answer_count": 8,
  "question_count": 0,
  "account_id": 9788211,
  "last_access_date": 1541648185,
  "reputation": 173,
  "user_id": 7253829,
  "display_name": "waymobetta"
}, {
  "badge_counts": {"bronze": 4, "silver": 0, "gold": 0},
  "up_vote_count": 3,
  "answer_count": 3,
  "question_count": 1,
  "account_id": 5611762,
  "last_access_date": 1539430768,
  "reputation": 43,
  "user_id": 4444243,
  "display_name": "Mobetoh"
}, {
  "badge_counts": {"bronze": 1, "silver": 0, "gold": 0},
  "up_vote_count": 0,
  "answer_count": 0,
  "question_count": 0,
  "account_id": 6361484,
  "last_access_date": 1437150901,
  "reputation": 1,
  "user_id": 4936855,
  "display_name": "Mobeth"
}
```

Note that `user_id` is their ID on Stack Overflow.
`account_id` is their ID Stack Exchange wide.

Comment: nice, this is definitely along the lines of what I was looking for. I'll just have to hope that there aren't duplicates of the name I search