# Is it possible to search questions by user name if I don't know the user id?

Tags: support, search

Lately I wanted to find a question which a specific user had asked. I still could remember his name and some text from the title.
Is it possible to search questions by user name, with something like

> javascript user:john doe

Or could I find the question any other way?

Comment: MSE: [How do I search a specific user's answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80832/571958)

Comment: See [How do I search?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching): "User Operators"

Comment: If you only know the username, use this to get the id: [Can I find a user's user_id with only their username for a Stack Exchange profile?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376353/6045800)

Comment: Note that with generic names (john being a perfect example), there's typically a ridiculous amount of accounts with that name. There's about 91548 accounts that match a search for "john", so unless you have something more concrete, you're gonna have a bad time

Comment: hm, the username is very common, there are over 2000 users with this name :(

Comment: Yes Zoe, there are lots of users, but I hoped to get at the question with the help of some title word I could remember.

Comment: Jeanne, so I need the user ID, but I do not know this, and getting it seems difficult. Okay, it was worth a try.

Comment: That's not much to go on though. If it's a generic question by a generic user on a generic tag, you'll probably have to bite the bullet and dig through search results. Alternative B, if you visited the question recently, is to search your browser history. But trying to find the question is probably gonna be a lot easier than trying to find the user

Comment: If you remember the *explicit* text from their question, you could search on your favourite search engine, and encapsulate the explicit text and their username in separate quotes: For example: `"John Doe" "When the value is a NULL like" site:stackoverflow.com`

Comment: @Larnu in addition, you can also restrict the results to a time frame, if you know when the question was from. For example, last 3 months or something.

Comment: Hi VLAZ, Zoe, I don't have a time frame and unfortunately no browser history either. I know it is an unusual case. :(

Comment: Hi Zoe, the problem is, I only remember vaguely some phrase of the title which returns about 250000 results. Perhaps with the help of the user name, there would be only 100 results or so.

Comment: Did you interact with the question in any way? Comment? Flag? Upvote? If so, then look at in your activitye under the relevant action.

Comment: Hi Larnu, no, unfortunately not.

Comment: Thank you, Larnu, I could not find the question on search engine either, but nice hint.

Comment: FYI, @AGuyCalledGerald , if you want to "ping" someone in the comments, you need to prefix the alias with an `@`; otherwise we have no idea you've attempted to respond to us. Myself, Zoe, VLAZ, and Jeanne would have not received a notification about any of your comments above.

Comment: Do you remember *how* you originally found the question? Were you looking through most recent or some other list or were you searching for something specific?

Answer (score 3):

There's no built-in way to filter results just by a username for a user whose specific account you can't find. As some of the commenters have shown, you can search for the user's username with or without quotation marks, but your results will vary wildly. The more information you *can* add as a filter or search parameter, the better your chances will be. For example, if you know one or more of the tags used for the question (e.g. [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)), that has the potential to greatly reduce the number of search results to potentially just a hundred or a few hundred, which is doable if you really need to find that question.

Knowing some of the words used in the question or title can also help, since you can put them in quotation marks to return results that only match that literal string.